# OpenCV TermCriteria Difference between CV_TERMCRIT_EPS and TermCriteria::EPS

Tags: c++, opencv, cluster-analysis, k-means

What is the difference between using `CV_TERMCRIT_EPS` and using `TermCriteria::EPS` inside the `TermCriteria` function?

I've just taken over a small bit of software written in C++ and am no expert. Using one version of **OpenCV**, the function only recognizes `TermCriteria::EPS` and on another version, it recognizes both.

`TermCriteria(TermCriteria::EPS+TermCriteria::COUNT,10, 1.0), clusterNum, KMEANS_PP_CENTERS, ImgCenters);`

`TermCriteria(CV_TERMCRIT_EPS + CV_TERMCRIT_ITER,10, 1.0), clusterNum, KMEANS_PP_CENTERS, ImgCenters);`

The first works or a few versions of **OpenCV** I have tried but the second only works on some. I can't seem to find anywhere that explains the difference between them.

Comment: Both are same, check their implementation files. The newer API (4.0 +) is moving towards everything without "CV_" , hence you see multiple types.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As the comment from Rakshith G B suggests, they are both the same but newer versions of OpenCV have moved to remove the CV_ prefixed.